# setting input value while editing in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display the current value of an input which is bind to a data model.

Here is my input field

```
input(ng-if="edit == $index", type='number', ng-model='item.price')
```

This one shows the price of a single item, when I'm trying to edit the price field. Normally in the span tag to show the total price, I'm multiplying price with quantity.

```
span(ng-if="edit != $index") item.quantity * item.price
```

How can I display this calculation result instead of a single item price as value of input?

Thank you

Comment: I'm confused... you want the user to modify the calculated total instead of the unit price?

Comment: Normally, I'm showing the total price, however when I press my edit button, value is shown as unit price. I want to display the total price while editing not the unit price. User sees total price before edit, but when user presses the edit button, he sees unit price

Comment: right, this doesn't make sense.  it is not normal for a calculated field to be the input value, since there isn't any way to determine which of the values used in the calculation should be adjusted to hit this new target (i.e., if your user changes the total price, does that imply that the unit price be adjusted or the quantity be adjusted to reach this new total value?)...  If you are trying to develop some sort of dynamic UI that allows this, you need to add a lot more detail explaining your formulas.

Comment: you *could* provide a variable to hold the calculated value, and bind an input to this variable, but the moment that the user modifies this value, the relationship between this value and the original values used to calculate it are lost, and the total becomes an arbitrary value.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I suddenly got the point. Actually, user sees the unit price and when he changes it and save it, I'm displaying the new total price so which is ok. I was a little bit confused, but I want my user to change unit price which will trigger the new total calculation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got it right. I wrote a plunker trying to reproduce your issue. Is this your problem?

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="item.price">
  <input type="number" ng-model="item.qty">
  <div>Total: {{item.price * item.qty}}</div>
</body>

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.item = {
    price: 10,
    qty: 5
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CnLieDhltMJD2jFp5Tzm

Comment: What I want is input field value has to be the total price before editting

Answer (score 0):

her is a plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/VIl9OymuqhMartw90hox?p=preview

html :

```
<input ng-model="item.price" />
<span> {{item.price * item.quantity}} </span>
```

Controller :

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.item = {'price' : 0 ,'quantity':5};
}
```

Comment: It doesn't give me the total price as the value of input field. If I set price 10, the input field's value will be also 10, not 50. I want my user to see 50 when editting the input

Comment: first if you put 10 in the input the total will be 50. second the behavior you want is strange. you should not let the user to edit the total